# ADO Pipelines updating variables from exe and using in each subseqnt stage

Tags: azure-devops

We have several scheduled automated pipelines which execute tests against integration tests environments A and B that switch with each deployment to ensure that there is always an environment available
There is a small exe that checks which environment is up and running before starting the test execution

Main pipeline:

```
parameters:
- name: BaseUrl
  type: string
  default: IntegrationTestA

- name: BaseUrlAlt
  type: string
  default: IntegrationTestB
  
variables:
  - name: ConnectionBaseUrl
    value: 'https://${{parameters.BaseUrl}}'

  - name: ConnectionBaseUrlAlt
    value: 'https://${{parameters.BaseUrlAlt}}'
  
- stage: GetEnv
  jobs:
  - job: GetEnv
    steps:
    - template: templates/GetEnv.yml
```

The GetEmv.yml template has the following:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    name: Execute
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'GetEnv.exe'
```

The GetEnv.exe has the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Setting connection base url to {currentUrl}");
Console.WriteLine($"Write-Host \"##vso[task.setvariable variable=ConnectionBaseUrl;isOutput=true]{currentUrl}");
```

Returning to the main pipline, on each subsequent stage I have to re pass the ConnectionBaseURL otherwise it has an empty value.

```
- stage Test1
  variables:
    ConnectionBaseUrl: $[ stageDependencies.GetEnvStage.GetEnvJob.outputs['GetEnvStep.ConnectionBaseUrl'] ]

    ...

    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: RePassVariable
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "Connection Base URL $(ConnectionBaseUrl)"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ConnectionBaseUrl;isOutput=true]$(ConnectionBaseUrl)"
      
- stage Test2
  variables:
    ConnectionBaseUrl: $[ stageDependencies.Test1.Test1Job.outputs['RePassVariable.ConnectionBaseUrl'] ]
    
    ... Do tests and repass variables
    
- stage Test3
  variables:
    ConnectionBaseUrl: $[ stageDependencies.Test2.Test2Job.outputs['RePassVariable.ConnectionBaseUrl'] ]
    
    ... Do tests and repass variables
```

In stages Test2 and Test3 the value of ConnectionBaseURL is empty if I use

```
  variables:
    ConnectionBaseUrl: $[ stageDependencies.GetEnvStage.GetEnvJob.outputs['GetEnvStep.ConnectionBaseUrl'] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've created your variable with `isOutput=true`, you can redefine the variable in whatever stage or job you want to use it like so:

```
stages:
- stage: GetEnvStage
  jobs:
  - job: GetEnvJob
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: GetEnvStep
      inputs:
        targetType: "inline"
        script: |
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ConnectionBaseUrl;isOutput=true]TestValue"

- stage: RunTest1
  variables:
    ConnectionBaseUrl: $[ stageDependencies.GetEnvStage.GetEnvJob.outputs['GetEnvStep.ConnectionBaseUrl'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: RunEnv1
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: "inline"
        script: |
          Write-Host "Print $(ConnectionBaseUrl)"

- stage: RunTest2
  variables:
    ConnectionBaseUrl: $[ stageDependencies.GetEnvStage.GetEnvJob.outputs['GetEnvStep.ConnectionBaseUrl'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: RunEnv2
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: "inline"
        script: |
          Write-Host "Print $(ConnectionBaseUrl)"

- stage: RunTest3
  variables:
    ConnectionBaseUrl: $[ stageDependencies.GetEnvStage.GetEnvJob.outputs['GetEnvStep.ConnectionBaseUrl'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: RunEnv3
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: "inline"
        script: |
          Write-Host "Print $(ConnectionBaseUrl)"
```

All subsequent stages will need to redeclare the variable. This is because each stage will be run with a clean agent, and variables defined within other stages will not persist.

Comment: Thank you.  This only works for the first stage following the GetEnvStage and not subsequent stages.
I have updated the example

Comment: @GazenGanados I have updated my answer with more description - in short, you need to redefine the variable every single stage using the stageDependencies. You do not need to change the syntax at all, as you are still getting the dependency from the same stage.